# anchor elements doesnt align properly

Tags: html, css

I was trying to align a anchor elements with some styles on it but it came out to be a mess and its not aligning properly, please see this illustration here

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x38gtiy1h711k2s/Untitled-1.jpg]

for that, I have this structure

```
<p style="margin-top: 0 !important; text-align: center; padding: 0 !important;" align="center"><span style="font-size: x-large; color: #00ccff;">Our information technology consulting services include:</span></p>

<div class="extend clear">
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/it-consulting-services">IT Consulting Services:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/remote-support">Remote Support:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/hosted-exchange">Hosted Exchange:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/remote-backup-services">Remote Backup Services:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/cloud-server-solutions">Cloud Server Solutions:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/cloud-solutions">Cloud Solutions:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/wi-fi-design-service-consultation">WiFi Design Service &amp; Consultation:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/application-development">Application Development:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/web-developments-and-design"> Web Development And Design:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/document-management-solutions">Document Management Solutions:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/network-design-and-implementation">Network Design And Implementation:</a>
<a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/voip-pbx-services">VoIP Phone Services:</a>
</div>
```

and the css for the above structure.

```
.circle{
color: #fff;
padding: 8px;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #363232;
background: #8c8b8b;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
vertical-align: top;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.extend{max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}
.clear{float: none; clear: both;}
```

so base on the above styling, what it should do, is it should align the anchor tags to the left and have a margin on each side by 5px, a padding on each side of 8px, a border radius of 3px in all sides, a text shadow, a font size of 17px, a background and a font color. Everthing works except for the style that should help the specified element align it self to the left, I search through the webs but nothing works and I tried playing on the styles but unfortunately nothing works so im looking here around for atleast an ideas or suggestions about how to align this properly.

Comment: "Archieves" is spelt wrong, it should be "Archives"

Comment: What browser and version are you seeing that in? Is it ok in any other browsers? Also you have a class of clear on the containing div. I assume that is a class to try and self clear its children. Could you add the css for clear and extend to the post please. I suspect there is some other css causing this that you havent shown in your question.

Comment: @DaveHaigh: please see my updated post, im using chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m.

Comment: I can not replicate it in Chrome. If you set up a jsfiddle with the replicated issue then someone maybe able to help efficiently

Comment: im testing it on ie10, firefox 28 and its all the same :(

Comment: I suspect also that maybe there are some styles or elements that is having a conflict with the specified element.

Comment: in the future inspect the rendered markup in the browser. The firebug extension in firebug is good. Then you can turn on/off styles and add new ones until the problem goes away. That will help you figure out the dodgy styling or markup that's causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

try `position:absolute;` to make `float:left;` work properly

Comment: What browser are you viewing it in? because when I view it in jsfiddle, it looks neat compared to your sample image

Comment: im using chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m and also been check in firefox 28 and ie10 and it went same. Right now im suspecting that maybe there are elements or styles that having a conflict witht he specified element so im checking it right now

Answer (score 0):

try `left:0px;` and absolute positioning `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, i have over hundreds of style codes and I cant bare to check one by one so i switch to alternative one, what i did is wrap the anchor tags to a div and then named  the div with a class circle and it works good! thank you everybody for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through you code, I'm not entirely sure when you set the anchor tags to `display: block;` and `float: left;`. You can just do `display: inline-block;` and you won't even need the `.clear` or the `.extend`.

The CSS:

```
.circle{
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #8c8b8b;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #363232;
}
```

The markup:

```
<div>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/it-consulting-services">IT Consulting Services:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/remote-support">Remote Support:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/hosted-exchange">Hosted Exchange:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/remote-backup-services">Remote Backup Services:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/cloud-server-solutions">Cloud Server Solutions:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/cloud-solutions">Cloud Solutions:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/wi-fi-design-service-consultation">WiFi Design Service &amp; Consultation:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/application-development">Application Development:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/web-developments-and-design"> Web Development And Design:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/document-management-solutions">Document Management Solutions:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/network-design-and-implementation">Network Design And Implementation:</a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://westchestercomputerconsulting.com/voip-pbx-services">VoIP Phone Services:</a>
</div>
```